Some bluetooth devices show up as "Connected" when it isn't in Windows 10
I have a bluetooth receiver device that I use with my wired headphones but the problem is, Windows 10 always lists it as "Connected" even when it's not. Therefore when I do want to connect it, I have to turn off my bluetooth and then on again. This is not ideal because I have other devices connected via bluetooth too such as my mouse and keyboard.
Another way I could connect it without needing to turn off bluetooth is to remove the pairing and then re-pair the device again which is too many steps for my liking, hence why I'm trying to solve the issue now.
I don't know if it matters but, this is the device I have: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003843651800.html
To get the common things out of the way, yes I have the latest bluetooth driver. Yes, I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the driver.
I saw someone else having a similar issue back in 2023 who posted in the Microsoft Answers site but no concrete answers either.

Indeed, the combo Windows 10 + some BT chipsets + some BT peripherals is, at times, problematic. Debian/Ubuntu Linux distros tend to work better in the same scenario.

@ChanganAuto unfortunately, I can't switch to Linux full time because of some critical software I use that don't do well in WINE or emulation. So I want to find a way to solve this somehow or at least, not have to remove the device and repair every time.

The more likely scenario is there's no solution, unless something change at software/drivers level. PS - Any modern computer can run virtual machines.

I'm back to answer my own question.
This might not work for everyone but worth a shot. I recently got a new pair of wireless earbuds and I paired that with Windows as well. After I did that, the bluetooth receiver stopped having ghost connection issue.
So in conclusion, if you encounter a similar issue to mine, try pairing a wireless earbud to Windows and it might help un-stuck the other one. Make sure it's a different model/brand. If you don't have another one, just borrow one from a friend and pair that. You don't need to connect to it.
